# How to calculate the Modular multiplicative inverse in pari?

Tags: pari, pari-gp

The modular multiplicative inverse is an integer ‘x’ such that.

a x ≡ 1 (mod m).

So, is there any way to calculate the Modular multiplicative inverse in pari\gp calculator ?

I am really sorry if this question is trivial or duplicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just `Mod(1/a, m)`, where `a` and `m` are your relatively prime numbers. See example for `a = 3` and `m = 1133` below.

```
lift(Mod(1/3, 1133))
> 378
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir, and I am sorry for not upvoting your answer because of my reputations number.